# Some browsers (IE8 and possibly others) not interpreting these javascript conditions correctly to determine an outbound link

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, google-analytics

I'm trying to isolate outbound links automatically with jQuery so that I can track them with Google Analytics. The following works in Chrome, but in IE8 and possibly some other browsers, links with `href="#1"` are being tracked as outbound links.

```
$('a').each(function () {
    if (this.href.length >= 3 && this.href.indexOf('http') >= 0 && this["hostname"].replace('www.','') != window.location.hostname.replace('www.','')) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

I'm guessing maybe IE8 adds the current url to the start of a `#` link, which would let it past the second condition, but the third condition should still stop it shouldn't it?

Does anyone know how I can stop this from happening?

Comment: If they are outbound how can you ensure that you can remove the `www.` subdomain and that they will still work?

Comment: @GeorgeReith I'm just removing the `www.` for the purpose of comparing the href domain with the document domain (in case one has www and one doesn't).

Comment: I need to learn to read -_-

Comment: I'm not sure you're accessing hostname properly at `this["hostname"]`? Nor are you accessing `this` properly.. should be: `$(this)`

Comment: @SetSailMedia `anything["property"]` is equivalent to `anything.property`.

Comment: @SetSailMedia And you only use `$(this)` if you want the jQuery object, not the real DOM element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the literal text of the `href` attribute, rather than how it's canonicalized by the browser, use:

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

rather than

```
this.href
```